# Make a array from lines made up of multiple variables

Tags: python, arrays

Right now I have this.

```
print (name.text.strip(), genre.text.strip(), bouquets.text.strip(), encryption.text.strip(), sid.text.strip(), nid.text.strip(), tid.text.strip(), sep = '\t')
```

This gives the output I desire. How can I add that line to a array instead of printing it?

I have tried

```
channel = (name.text.strip(), genre.text.strip(), bouquets.text.strip(), encryption.text.strip(), sid.text.strip(), nid.text.strip(), tid.text.strip(), sep = '\t')
channels.append (channel)
```

But it doesn't work.

```
channel = (name.text.strip(), genre.text.strip(), bouquets.text.strip(), encryption.text.strip(), sid.text.strip(), nid.text.strip(), tid.text.strip(), sep = '\t')
                                                                                                                                                            ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I think it's because of the tab separation maybe?

Does anyone know how to do this properly?

Comment: python have lists not arrays. and list is defind as `channel = []` not `channel = ()`

Comment: What do you mean by "But it doesn't work."? What happens with your second code snippet and what do you want to it to do differently?

Comment: Did you understand that `sep` is an argument of `print` ?

Comment: `str.join([name.text.strip(), genre.text.strip(), bouquets.text.strip(), encryption.text.strip(), sid.text.strip(), nid.text.strip(), tid.text.strip()])`

Comment: Remove `sep = '\t'` from your last element and use square brackets: `[name.text.strip(), ...]`

Comment: @Itay, I would suppose OP does not need to use `join`. He wants a list output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to build the `str` and then it can be added to your array.

```py
channel = "\t".join([
    name.text.strip(),
    genre.text.strip(),
    bouquets.text.strip(),
    encryption.text.strip(),
    sid.text.strip(),
    nid.text.strip(),
    tid.text.strip()
])
channels.append(channel)
```

Since you're applying `text.strip()` to each element, you can simplify this using a list comprehension:

```py
elements = [name, genre, bouquets, encryption, sid, nid, tid]
channel = "\t".join(
    x.text.strip() for x in elements
)
channels.append(channel)
```

Answer (score 0):

If "properly" also mean reducing code duplication, you can use:

```py
channel = (name, genre, bouquets, encryption, sid, nid, tid)
channel = "\t".join(item.text.strip() for item in channel)
channels.append(channel)
```